# Trying to store an equation into a variable

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out how to store the calculated gross pay into the grossPay variable to use it for calculating net pay. Throws me off when using a struct.

```
#include<string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Workers {
    string name;
    double hourlyWage;
    int hoursWorkedPerDay;
    int hoursWorkedPerWeek;

};
int healthTax = 130;
double otherTaxes = 0.17;
double grossPay;

int main() {
    Workers JohnDoe;
    JohnDoe.name = "John Doe";
    JohnDoe.hourlyWage = 8.50;
    JohnDoe.hoursWorkedPerDay = 6;
    cout<<"- John Doe's weekly earnings - "<< endl;
    cout<<"Hourly rate: $8.50" << endl;
    cout<<"Hours worked per day: 6" << endl;
    cout<<"Gross pay: $" << 7 * (JohnDoe.hourlyWage * JohnDoe.hoursWorkedPerDay)<<endl; // gross pay
    grossPay; // how to store gross pay into this variable?
    cout<<"Net pay: $" << otherTaxes * (grossPay - healthTax) / 100; // net pay  
}
```

Comment: `grossPay = 7 * JohnDoe.hourlyWage * JohnDoe.hoursWorkedPerDay`

Comment: Why you can't just `grossPay= 7 * (JohnDoe.hourlyWage * JohnDoe.hoursWorkedPerDay)`

Answer (score 4):

I think you may not be understanding how variables work. You don't store the formula, you store the result of calculating the formula:

```
     double grossPay =  7 * (JohnDoe.hourlyWage * JohnDoe.hoursWorkedPerDay);
```

Comment: I think he rather means something like a function

Comment: @Saeid I really doubt he is asking about lambdas or function pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are right, but a slightly better solution would be a function wich takes a `Worker` reference as parameter and returns the result:

```
double getGrossPay(const Workers& worker) {
        return 7 * (worker.hourlyWage * worker.hoursWorkedPerDay);
}
```

Then simply:

```
cout<<"Gross pay: $" << getGrossPay(JohnDoe) <<endl; // gross pay
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you hae to do :

```
double grossPay =  7 * ( JohnDoe.hourlyWage * JohnDoe.hoursWorkedPerDay );
```

Then you can use it, in this case, print it :

```
cout<<"Gross pay: $" << grossPay <<endl;
```

Comment: And what is the difference of your answer with the Neil's answer?

Comment: I'm just saying that after you created the variable, you can use it.